# Laravel: Issue with calling custom Facade

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 and I'm creating a custom Facade, but I cannot recall it with `LogActivity::log($payload)` but only with `LogActivityFacade::log($payload)`.

Cannot see where is my fault...

**app\Helpers\LogActivityFacade.php**

```php
<?php


namespace App\Helpers;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class LogActivityFacade extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'logactivity';
    }
}
```

**app\Helpers\LogActivityHelper.php**

```php
<?php


namespace App\Helpers;


use App\Repositories\LogActivityRepository;

class LogActivityHelper
{
    public function log($payload)
    {
        $repository = new LogActivityRepository();
        $repository->store($payload);
    }
}
```

**app\Providers\LogActivityServiceProvider.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use App\Helpers\LogActivityHelper;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class LogActivityServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('logactivity', function() {
            return new LogActivityHelper();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**config/app.php**

In providers array

```php
[...]
App\Providers\LogActivityServiceProvider::class,
```

In alias array

```php
'LogActivity' => App\Helpers\LogActivityFacade::class,
```

I tried also `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan config:clear`, but I can access to the Facade (and it works...) only with `LogActivityFacade::log()` instead of `LogActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. Laravel doesn't create new classes for you it just proxies methods from the service class in the facade using the `__call` magic method.   If you take a peek at, for example, the `Auth` or `Route` facade in the vendor directory you will see that they are named `Auth` and `Route` respectively not `AuthFacade` and `RouteFacade`. So just name your facade `LogActivity`. If you need to differentiate it from the service class you can use namespacing or just postfix the service class name with something as you have already done.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this for easy access to the facades**

```
namespace App\Facade;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

abstract  class BaseFacade extends Facade
{

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return static::class ;
    }

    /**
     * @param $class
     */
    static function shouldProxyTo($class)
    {
        app()->singleton(self::getFacadeAccessor(),$class);
    }

}
```

**extend other facades**

```
namespace App\Facade\Plugins;


use App\Facade\BaseFacade;

/**
 * @method static convertPersianNumberToEnglish($number)
 * @method static bool checkDataIsTrue(array  $results = [])
 * @method static string|null removeFileTypeName(string $string = null)
 */
class GlobalPluginsFacade extends BaseFacade
{

}
```

**register in services provider**

```
public function boot()
{

  // global facades
  GlobalPluginsFacade::shouldProxyTo(GlobalPluginsRepo::class);

}
```

**And easy to use.**

```
GlobalPluginsFacade::getFunction();
```